# spark-notebook: command not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to set up spark notebook on my laptop following the instructions listed in http://spark-notebook.io I gave the command `bin/spark-notebook` and I'm getting:

> -bash: bin/spark-notebook: command not found

How to resolve this? I want to run spark-notebook for spark standalone and scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download

```
spark-notebook-0.7.0-pre2-scala-2.10.5-spark-1.6.3-hadoop-2.7.2-with-parquet.tqz
```

Set the path in bashrc 
Example :

```
$sudo gedit ~/.bashrc 

export SPARK_HOME=/yor/path/
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK+HOME/bin
```

Then start your notebook following command...

```
$spark-notebook
```